# Corrupted font after Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: upgrade, libreoffice, fonts

I updated Ubuntu this morning and had a LibreOffice document open at the time. During the upgrade all the a's in the document were replaced with dots. This seems to have taken place with the Liberations Sans font only. When replacing the font with Times New Roman there is no problem. I noticed during the upgrade that the fonts-droid package was upgraded. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and LibreOffice 4.2.4.2. Has anybody had the same issue, and how can this be resolved?

Comment: Is it ever wise to do a system upgrade whilst running an application? Did you then replace the Times New Roman with your original Liberations Sans Font and has that resolved the issue?

Comment: No, with hindsight this was probably not, but considering that I have done this so many times without a problem, I guess I got used to it. I did change the font to Times New Roman and this resolved the issue. It is just that the Liberation Font has this issue with a's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have disappeared after changing to Times New Roman and then back to Liberations Sans font. The a's are not dots after this step. There is no explanation but it works.